# Deleting a specific item on a list with react js

Tags: reactjs

So I am trying to remove a todo item from its current array and it is not working. When server starts, I tried console.log but no argument is being passed.

Todos returns an array [].

Here's my code:

```
handleTodoDelete = (deleteTodo) => {
    const remainingItems = this.state.todo.filter (todo => {  
      return todo !== deleteTodo;
    });

    this.setState({
      todos: remainingItems
    });

  }
```

**My return code has this:**

```
 return (
          <li
            className={completeClass}
            onClick={() => this.handleTodoClick(todo)}>
            {todo.description}

          <button onClick= 
{(todo)=>this.handleTodoDelete(todo)}>delete</button>

</li>
```

Comment: It's seems that you're setting the filtering the `todo` array in state, but you're setting `todos`. Should you just be messing with `todo` or `todos`?

Comment: it works when im passing thru ... :( done !=isdone - {this.state.todos.map(todo => {
            let completeClass = "";
            if (todo.isDone) {
              completeClass = "complete";
            }
            return (
              <li
                className={completeClass}
                onClick={() => this.handleTodoClick(todo)}
              >
                {todo.description}

Comment: if `this.state.todos.map` is working, maybe try `this.state.todos.filter`. You have `this.state.todo.filter` which is todo singular instead of plural. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do:

```
const remainingItems = this.state.todos.filter (todo => {  
  return todo !== deleteTodo;
});

this.setState({
  todos: remainingItems
});
```

Or try to do:

```
const remainingItems = this.state.todo.filter (todo => {  
  return todo !== deleteTodo;
});

this.setState({
  todo: remainingItems
});
```

It seems like you want to use `todos` or `todo` in state and not both.

Here is some working code with a filter maybe it'll help you have a reference to compare:

```js
const app = document.querySelector('#app');

const todoOne = { id: 1, description: "Code this." };
const todoTwo = { id: 2, description: "Make that." };

const todos = [
  todoOne,
  todoTwo,
];

const todoToRemove = todoOne;

const removedTodos = todos.filter(
  (todo) => todo.id != todoToRemove.id
)

app.innerHTML = `
  <p>To Dos (Original): <br>${JSON.stringify(todos)}</p>
  <p>To Dos (Deleted): <br>${JSON.stringify(removedTodos)}</p>
`;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Snippet</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it still wont delete when i changed it to "this.state.todos.filter"

Comment: You likely want your state to match, but that may be a different issue. `todo !== deleteTodo` is comparing objects instead of values. Could you compare and id instead? `todo.id !== deleteTodo.id`

Answer (score 0):

You should always create another list or object when changing list or object in react redux application.

and the best way to do it, is via spread operator.

```
handleTodoDelete = (deleteTodo) => {
    let state = this.state;
    let newTodo = [...state.todo.filter(todo => todo.id !== deleteTodo.id)];
    state.todo = newTodo;
    this.setState({ state });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would you mind adding some clarifying or explanatory text to your code?